# What object is created in this assignment?

Tags: c++, qt

When I was reading some codes written with Qt, I came to this line:

```
::QFlags<QFileDialog::Option> cppArg6 = QFileDialog::{};
```

Any idea how right side of this assignment should be compiled? What is the meaning of right side? Because I expect to see something after `::` and before `{}` in the right side. My question is not related to Qt at all, I just want to know how it is possible to write a code in C++ that does not generate any error for the right side of this expression.

Comment: Where did you read these some codes?  I once knew a kid that learned math on the street.  He tried to divide by zero once, and his head exploded.  Friends don't let friends do street math.

Comment: *"My question is not related to Qt at all"* - You may think so, but since Qt uses moc to preprocess files *before* compiling as C++, you shouldn't assume it's standard C++ just like that.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it maybe moc-related, because this a file generated in build directory during build process. But even in that case, code should be compiled and I cannot find any way to compile it rather than ridiculous macros like using `#define {} ....`. But it is during build process of https://github.com/KDE/falkon

Comment: Perhaps something went wrong during generation or it is an intermediate step before the final source? Does the build run through? Is this file given to g++?

Comment: @Sebastian code was passed to g++, but code did not compile. That's why I checked to see what's wrong and I came to see this. Because I couldn't understand it, I thought maybe it is something that I don't understand (Since at least it seems generation was successful). But maybe you are right and problem is with generation. I try changing Qt version and see if it works.